# Converting rgb to hex in Swift

Tags: swift, hex, rgb

I'm trying to convert my rgb color to a hex value. Unfortunately it is always returning 000000. Here is my code I have tried:

```swift
let red = CGFloat(drand48())
let green = CGFloat(drand48())
let blue = CGFloat(drand48())

let hexValue = String(format:"%02X", red) + String(format:"%02X", green) + String(format:"%02X", blue)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a better way to generate the 3 random numbers and convert them into a hex string:

```
let red = Int.random(in: 0...255)
let green = Int.random(in: 0...255)
let blue = Int.random(in: 0...255)
let hex = String(format:"%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that your numbers are `CGFloat` in the range 0.0 to 1.0. But your string format treats them as `Int` values.

Besides that, the use of `drand48` requires that you seed them first.